# access to page available only when Edit permission is set

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I have a problem with authorized users that are not a superuser.
When I want to access a page having only a View permission, then there is an error:
request redirect to address http://localhost/dnn/Default.aspx?tabid=93&error=An%20unexpected%20error%20has%20occurred&content=0
and in logs I can see that a null exception occured.

This problem does not occur when I also specify the Edit permission for this user/his role. Why is that? It looks like a serious bug. 
I'm looking for a workaround. Can somebody suggest something?

[edit]

The log:

```
 AbsoluteURL:/dnn/Default.aspx

    DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

    ExceptionGUID:4fd8d504-48bc-4c52-b572-355a01dfffc3

    AssemblyVersion:

    PortalId:-1

    UserId:-1

    TabId:-1

    RawUrl:

    Referrer:

    UserAgent:

    ExceptionHash:RRJaZSdhuu5HQglro3JdqxRzeWE=

    Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    StackTrace:

    InnerMessage:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    InnerStackTrace:

    w DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Authentication.Login.OnLoad(EventArgs e) w 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() w 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


    Source:

    FileName:

    FileLineNumber:0

    FileColumnNumber:0

    Method:

    Server Name: fujitsu-a514
```

Comment: I guess you don't know the fact that we are unable to connect to your `localhost`

Comment: I quess you don't know the fact that I only added this link as a reference to show the query string

Comment: Can you show us the detailed error from the Event Log? And is the page empty? If not it could be a module that is causing the error?

Comment: I added the log but this is of no use in my opinion. Unfortunatelly I don't know how to attach the VS debugger to the DNN sources and not for single, custom module.

Comment: Is it a custom module then it will be difficult to solve without knowing a lot more. Can't you ask the author of the module?

Comment: On this specific page there is only a build in HTML module.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the permissions as you have them defined?  Have you overridden any settings on the module level